# python argparser: how do i associate specific arguments with specific functions

Tags: python

I'm just new to python and new the argparser library.  I'm trying to figure out how to write a script file that has many different functions, each one requiring different arguments.

So for example, I might have the following method signatures:

```
 def function1(a,b,c):
 def function2(x,y,z):
 def function3():
```

**What I have so far**

So far, I've added all possible arguments as optional items like so:

```
import argparse

 def function1(lc,uc):
     assert(lc is not None)
     assert(uc is not None)
     #do something

 def function2():
     #do something else

 def function3(lr,ur):
     assert(lr is not None)
     assert(ur is not None)
     #do something else

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='This is the description of my program')
parser.add_argument('-lc','--lower_create', type=int, help='lower range value for creating mailboxes')
parser.add_argument('-uc','--upper_create', type=int, help='upper range value for creating mailboxes')
parser.add_argument('-lr','--lower_reserve', type=int, help='lower range value for reserving mailboxes')
parser.add_argument('-ur','--upper_reserve', type=int, help='upper range value for reserving mailboxes')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

So far so good.  When I run the script like so:

```
 python3 myutils.py
```

I dont' get any errors.

When I do this:

```
 python3 myutils.py -h
```

it gives me a nice help system.

But what isn't clear to me is how to associate specific args with specific functions.  This is the error I get when I invoke function1 for example:

```
lab-1:/var/www/localhost/htdocs/pvmaildbapp# python3 myutils.py function1
usage: myutils.py [-h] [-lc LOWER_CREATE] [-uc UPPER_CREATE]
                       [-lr LOWER_RESERVE] [-ur UPPER_RESERVE]
myutils.py: error: unrecognized arguments: function1
```

I'm still making my way for the first time through the argparse docs so I'm sure I missed something.  But any tips / pointers in the right direction would be appreciated

**EDIT 1**

Based on answers below from d_kennetz and UtahJarhead (thank you btw) , I have changed the code to include a "dest" parm for each argument and I also need an arg for the function the user is trying to call, like so:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='This is the description of my program')

parser.add_argument('func_name',help='name of function you want to run')

parser.add_argument('-lc','--lower_create', type=int, dest='lc', help='lower range value for creating mailboxes')
parser.add_argument('-uc','--upper_create', type=int, dest='uc', help='upper range value for creating mailboxes')
parser.add_argument('-lr','--lower_reserve', type=int, dest='lr', help='lower range value for reserving mailboxes')
parser.add_argument('-ur','--upper_reserve', type=int, dest='ur', help='upper range value for reserving mailboxes')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

and then, I've also changed the definition of function1 to look like this:

```
 def function1(lc,uc):
     assert(lc is not None)
     assert(uc is not None)
     print('made it here')
     return True
```

lastly, i now try to call via commandline like this:

```
 python3 myutils.py function1 -lc 1 -uc 3
```

but it doesn't call function1 at all.
I'm clearly missing one more piece of the puzzle.

i think what I need at the end of my code - after I call parse_args() is something like this:  (pseudocode)

```
select case args.func_name
   case 'function1'
       make sure i have lc and uc
   case function3
       make sure i have lr and ur
end select
```

Is this correct?

**Edit 2**

ok so i think i've connected all the dots.

1. I was definitely missing a positional argument to save the function
   name that the user wants to call.
2. I'm still using optional argument
   notation to save the values for lc, uc etc.
3. The piece i was missing was logic to manually match up the functions with args.  For some reason, I thought I'd get some of this plumbing for free with the argparse library.

So now I have code that looks like this:

```
args = parser.parse_args()
#print(args)
if args.func_name == 'function1':
    #make sure we have lc and uc
    assert(args.lc is not None)
    assert(args.uc is not None)
    function1(args.lc, args.uc)
elif args.func_name == 'function3':
    assert(args.lr is not None)
    assert(args.ur is not None)
    function3(args.lr, args.ur)
elif args.func_name == 'function2':
    function2()
```

The code works.  But i feel like there's probably a more graceful way to handle the last series of if/elifs that I have ... As this utility file grows and I add more methods to it, the if elif list will grow pretty big.

Comment: The last line `args ...` just collects the entered arguments. You now have to write code that checks them and starts the desired functions. Add a last line `print (args)`, then you see the args and will get an idea on how to write if clauses to start the functions.

Comment: @576i ah ok.  so for example, I can add logic to function1 that looks inside the args variable and grabs what it needs?

Comment: you could check if args.lc is not none and then start function 1, check if args.lr is not none and start function 3.... google for an argparse tutorial for more (I highly recommend spending an hour once learning more about this)

Comment: If you use arghandler you can easily specify subcommands with varying positional and optional parameters. Worth having a look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To explain where you have gone wrong a bit, you need to pass a destination to your argparse argument so it can be called as a variable in your code. Secondly, variables used in a function call such as `def function1(lc, uc):` are going to be local to that function so they will not be interpreted as globals. This is a good thing as we generally don't want to pass globals to a function call (although there are some exceptions).

Here is my modification to your code:

```
import argparse
import sys

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='This is the description of my program')
parser.add_argument('-lc','--lower_create', type=int, dest="lc", help='lower range value for creating mailboxes')
parser.add_argument('-uc','--upper_create', type=int, dest="uc", help='upper range value for creating mailboxes')
parser.add_argument('-lr','--lower_reserve', type=int, dest="lr", help='lower range value for reserving mailboxes')
parser.add_argument('-ur','--upper_reserve', type=int, dest="ur", help='upper range value for reserving mailboxes')

args = parser.parse_args()

def function1(lc,uc):
    assert(lc is not None)
    assert(uc is not None)
    return True

print(function1(args.lc, args.uc))
```

First you see that I passed an option called `dest=` in my `parser.add_argument()` call. This will tell the python code what that argument is going to be called as in the program.

Then, I wrote your function to return `True` if a value was passed to the function.

Lastly, my call to `print` calls my argparse `dest=` variables by the following syntax `args.lc, args.uc`. This is how you call argparse arguments in your python code.

Lastly when I run the command and pass values:

```
$ python3.5 argfun.py -lc 4 -uc 0
```

outputs:

```
4
```

Comment: thanks for this clear explanation.  One related question though.  The command line example i need to work is really "python3 myscript.py function1 -lc 4 -uc 10. I don't want the script itself to call any functions.  the user will trigger whatever function they need. I'll test out your code but it feels like your answer doesn't address this?

Comment: Please see my updated post under section "EDIT 1".  Thanks.

Comment: I just looked through your code, and I think your if/elif/else loop is actually a perfectly fine way to conditionally call functions apart from writing a program (which is outside the scope of SO). I actually have conditional function calls in some of my programs. Off the top of my head I have one that runs `if infile.endswith(".txt"): pd.read_table(infile); elif infile.endswith(".csv"): pd.read_csv(infile)` This is fairly common.

Comment: so i can't accept both your answers, but you both contributed to the final stuff.  So I guess I upvote one of yous and accept the other as the answer.  thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to use a required positional argument, but you have no positional arguments set up in your argparse setup.  To fix this, it sounds like you want to add this extra line:

```
parser.add_argument('func_name', help='function name')
```

As it is, you have created 4 variables, `args.lower_create`, `args.upper_create`, `args.lower_reserve`, `args.upper_reserve`.  If you had passed in something like `python3 myutils.py -lc 1234` then `args.lower_create` would have a value of `1234`.

Edit:  I think perhaps you may be not including the appropriate input.  It's expecting something akin to:

```
python3 myutils.py -lc 0 -uc 1 -lr 2 -ur 3
```

Comment: i think you're right.  I need to add a positional argument as the first arg ...so that it knows i'm expecting a function name.  But ... i still don't understand how to pass the args to the right funciton.  Please see Edit 1

Comment: I solved my problem using both answers. So i just accepted the first one as the answer and upvoted your answer as well.  Thanks

Comment: Just for future knowledge, all information you pass in are kept within `args`.  This is done where you say `args = parser.parse_args()`.  You can `print(args)` to see what's there. In that namespace, you can then reference them with `args.lower_create`, `args.upper_create`, `args.lower_reserve`, and `args.upper_reserve` as above.

Comment: Thank you for your patient help!

Comment: No problem.  Good luck!